# Android array loop returning only last record

Tags: android, json, for-loop, android-volley

I am working on the android volley, where I am getting a response from the server as nested JSON,  Below is my code.

```
private void getUserData() {
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, MyUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("intrecv");


                    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                        JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ob.getString("image_title"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"erre",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

JSON O/P

```
{
    "intrecv": [{
        "image_title": "BM35255",
        "image_url": "https:\/abcd\/member_photo\/BM35255\/thumbs_small\/BM352551131.jpg"
        
    }, {
        "image_title": "BM654745",
        "image_url": "https:\/\/abcd.com\/member_photo\/BM654745\/thumbs_small\/BM6547453157.jpg"
    }],
    "visitors": [{
        "image_title": "BM25956",
        "image_url": "https:\/\/abcd.com\/member_photo\/BM25956\/thumbs_small\/BM259562382.jpg"
    }, {
        "image_title": "BM23697",
        "image_url": "https:\/\/abcd.com\/member_photo\/BM23697\/thumbs_small\/BM236973084.jpg"
    }]
}
```

So far I am getting a response from the server as json (which is valid json).
When I am trying to loop the response, it giving me only last record of response in Toast.

Will anybody please put me in the right direction, where i am making the mistake.
Any help with these will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste here the json object

Comment: Perhaps the all the previous toasts are overwritten by the last. Try showing it differently, fi. by using `Log.d("JSON", ob.getString("image_title"));` and check your console for results

Comment: @PavelPoley json response added

Comment: @Michiel, hi there as u suggested, yeap all the records are now visible in LOG